# Conditional tag for wordpress pages

Tags: php, wordpress, conditional-statements

I'm trying to get a header image to display differently on certain category pages. For example, a image of a football player will be displayed on all the posts with the category of football.

This needs to be displayed on archive pages too, so I used the conditional tag

```
is_category('football')
```

for example, this worked fine. Though it doesn't show the header image on the actual post page itself. Is there a way I can make this work somehow? Maybe another conditional tag in there somewhere?

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: at what files you are using this code?

Comment: it's in the file of header.php

Answer (score 1):

Actually in `WordPress` you can use a conditional tags in many ways. In your question you mentioned you want to check if it's in the category/archive page and you know that how to do it but in a comment you mentioned you want to check `if a post belongs to a category` and in this case it could be on a single post page.

To check in the single post page you can use

```
if(is_single() && in_category('football'))
```

You may check these links [in_category](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/in_category), [is_object_in_term](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/is_object_in_term) and [is_single](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/is_single).

Comment: Thanks for the answer, that works on the post pages now, but the archive page doesn't display my image. Any reason?

Comment: @rowefx, check [is_archive()](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/is_archive) and [is_post_type_archive()](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/is_post_type_archive).